# to pass filepath in url

Tags: java, list, url, httpresponse

I want to hit a url and pass some filepath in it :
here is the sample url:

> localhost:8080/CoreEngine/addrecording/obd_msisdn_pankaj/9958557426/9999620647/{D:\Islamic\first}

Last one is a filepath.

i am receiving this at my controller as :

> @RequestMapping(value="/addrecording/{tablename}/{aparty}/{bparty}/{filename}")

```
 public @ResponseBody String addRecord(@PathVariable("tablename") String tablename, @PathVariable("aparty") String aparty, @PathVariable("bparty") String bparty , @PathVariable("filename") String filename)
{
return "done";
}
```

It works for url :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/CoreEngine/addrecording/thispank/356783956/67456/gdshhfdsg
```

But if i hit url :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/CoreEngine/addrecording/thispank/356783956/67456/E:\out_of_ofc\songs\Spirit.mp3
```

It does not work for filepath and gives following error at browser :

> it gives error : vedio playback aborted due to  network error

if i hit url as

```
127.0.0.1:8080/CoreEngine/addrecording/obd_msisdn_pankaj/9958557426/9999620647/?path=E:\out_of_ofc\songs\Spirit.mp3
```

> The requested resource is not available.

Can anybody provide a solution to this problem.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Are you getting errors? If so paste the stack trace

Comment: @StuWhyte : i have edited the question to make it more clear

Comment: The usual solution would be to pass the additional information as a parameter -- `localhost:8080/CoreEngine/addrecording/obd_msisdn_pankaj/9958557426/9999620647/?path=D:\Islamic\first`. That lets the URI be used to specify the service you're contacting, while the parameter says what you want that service to do for you.

Comment: @keshlam : i have hit url : localhost:8080/CoreEngine/addrecording/obd_msisdn_pankaj/9958557426/9999620647/?path=D:\Islamic\first      or as localhost:8080/CoreEngine/addrecording/obd_msisdn_pankaj/9958557426/9999620647/?filename=D:\Islamic\first    where    
filename is parameter through which i am mapping but it is still not able to recognize and same problem persists

Comment: Do i have to make change in my request mapping method

Comment: (1) What happens when you give that URI without the parameter? Are you sure the URI you're trying to contact exists? (2) The service you're contacting needs to be written to do something with the parameter

Comment: (1) Yes url is working properly if i give normal string instead of filepath as last parameter. it returns an output string as "done".       (2) but when i enter filepath it returns above said error. so service has no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using GET request method instead of post request and using @requestparam method.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addrecording", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String addRecord(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,@RequestParam("tablename") String tablename, @RequestParam("aparty") String aparty, @RequestParam("bparty") String bparty , @RequestParam("filename") String filename)
```